# Using block of statements vs using functions in python

Tags: python, performance, function, block

Which one is better in terms of performance:

```
def check():
   if (statement1 and
       statement2 and
       statement3):
     return True
   else: 
     return False

def doIt():
   if check():
     perform()
```

vs

```
def doIt():
   if (statement1 and
       statement2 and
       statement3):
      perform()
```

Comment: Why don't you measure yourself?

Comment: @TadeuszA.Kadłubowski Maybe he doesn't know how to? Your comment is certainly not helpful.

Comment: you could do your check function like this:
`def check(): return stat1 and stat2 and stat3`

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to measure it. Would you please show me how?

Comment: @shenshei why do you think that is better?

Comment: Just because `if (a) then True else False` is the same as `a` and you will get one step less.

Comment: This is massively, massively premature optimisation. There is *no way* a Python program can be so time-critical that this matters (if it was that critical, you shouldn't be writing it in Python to start with).

Comment: @Daniel: Yep. Also, worrying about performance without any tools to measure actual performance is cargo cult programming. If you need performance, how would you know whether any modification got you any improvement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (and only if) you're having performance issues, [time it](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) yourself:

```
% python -m timeit -c '
statement1 = True
statement2 = True
statement3 = True

def perform():
    pass

def check():
    if (statement1 and
        statement2 and
        statement3):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def doIt():
    if check():
        perform()

doIt()
'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.37 usec per loop
```

If you're not having performance issues, follow [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) and remember [what Donald Knuth said about premature optimisation](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29).

Comment: how do I add "timeit" to my program and when my program ends it displays the run time in the end on screen?

Comment: Please see [the linked documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) for details. You're better off just testing a small snippet.

Answer (score 4):

Don't bother. The former is more readable, use that and if your app suffers from performance issues, profile the code. If you identify this as the problem, you can inline the function call.

Generally speaking though, function calls are expensive in Python so if the invocation to `check` is going to be run a VERY large number of times in a loop, it can affect the performance. Even so, inlining it at the outset is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just from my basic software knowledge, I think the function call would cost extra effort then coding directly in side block.

Usually, the function call have to record the current coding pointer for later return from function call.

Function should make your code more readable and reusable function is easy for debugging and maintaining.